# Two div overlapping with variable height = without height on container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It is quite easy to make two div overlap when the size of the container div is known but what if the div heigh cannot ?

I tried to do it without manipulating container height: 
http://jsfiddle.net/AJfAV/ 
But `#text2` go over `#text3` and do not "push" it.
How can the `#container` be resized automatically ?

I manage to achieve my goal using jquery ui but I feel this is not an elegant solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/AJfAV/6/

Comment: is it a problem if #container has a fixed width??

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

**[Updated fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/AJfAV/1/)**

I'm setting `height` to the default, `auto`, using jQuery, like this:

```
$("#container").css("height", "auto");
```

You can also set: `height: auto;` in CSS.

Comment: I added a solution to exactly show what I was expecting but I am surprised height of container has to be fixed  http://jsfiddle.net/AJfAV/5/.
In your solution/fiddle, "text3: This should appear below text1 and text2" does not appear below text1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need position:absolute? You can use absolute positioning if you don't want to do any arrangement, but a placement. The absolute positioning takes an element completely out of the flow of elements. They know nothing of its existent.

You may use floats and a technique to enclose floats. I'm using clear:

```
.cl-left {
    clear: left;
    height: .1px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Don't forget to add `<div class="cl-left">&nbsp;</div>`.

In addition, a negative margin is used. Therefore, #text2 is nailed to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/AJfAV/7/

Comment: Indeed I do not need absolute. I would like to keep the flow of elements as they are but I am not able to find a solution without position:absolute.

Comment: You can use floats but css tables won't work because fading affect the display property. Besides, margins aren't applicable to table cells.

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved if you removed absolute positioning of `#text1` and `#text2`.

and make `#text2` overlap `#text1` by making both `float:left` and set `margin-left:-30px` for `#text2`.

now let's test it: http://jsfiddle.net/RPe4H/

the problem now is that when `#text1` is toggled, `#text2` will float to top left of `#container`, this happening because JQuery set  `display:none` on the element when toggling is done.

now to solve this, put #text1 and #text2 inside containers with same width, so `#text` doesn't affect the flow when it is set to `display:none`, also you must set `min-height:1px` on the container of `#text1`.

now it is working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/MyyF6/1/